# Compare dataframe with list and update a new column in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

Edited!!

Team,

Need suggestion in below request.

I have a static list df2= c("Maths,"Science","Engg). I need to compare each column of df1 with df2 and check if all these combinations are present or not. It can appear separately or in combination with other values as well. But if all three present, then create a column as 'YES' else 'NO'.

Similarly, Maths is given weightage of 1, Science =2 and Engg=3.

A new dataframe df3 is created with column as 'weightage' and mention the highest available values  in the row(as per weightage).

Please find the data below,

df1-Input
[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV0IN.png)

```
dput(input)

structure(list(Col_1 = c("Maths/Science", "Engg", "Commerce", 
"Engg"), Col_2 = c("Science L", "Science/Maths", "English,", 
"Science/Engg"), Col_3 = c("Commerce", "NA", "NA", "Science"), 
    Col_4 = c("CS/Engg", "NA", "NA", "NA")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Expected Output**
[df1_soln](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hstyv.png)

```
structure(list(Col_1 = c("Maths/Science", "Engg", "Commerce", 
"Engg"), Col_2 = c("Science L", "Science/Maths", "English,", 
"Science/Engg"), Col_3 = c("Commerce", "NA", "NA", "Science"), 
    Col_4 = c("CS/Engg", "NA", "NA", "NA"), Flag = c("YES", "YES", 
    "NO", "YES")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

df3 [df3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4e4A.png)

```
structure(list(Col_1 = c("Maths", "Engg", "Commerce", "Engg"), 
    Col_2 = c("Science L", "Science/Maths", "English,", "Science/Engg"
    ), Col_3 = c("Commerce", "NA", "NA", "Science"), Col_4 = c("CS/Engg", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA"), Weightage = c("Maths", "Science/Maths", 
    "NA", "Science/Engg")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

############## Edited to include output   ########

```
dput(df)

structure(list(Col_1 = c("Maths/Science", "Engg", "Commerce", 
"Engg"), Col_2 = c("Science L", "Science/Maths", "English,", 
"Science/Engg"), Col_3 = c("Commerce", "NA", "NA", "Science"), 
    Col_4 = c("CS/Engg", "NA", "NA", "NA")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py8BA.png)

Comment: Please post your data using `dput()`, not pictures. Paste the results into your question and delete the images.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach to the first of your two questions (please post the second question as a separate question):

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  # create row identifier:
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  # cast all `Col` columns longer:
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Col")) %>%
  # separate the "/" separated values into their own rows:
  separate_rows(value, sep = "/") %>%
  # is any of the strings in `df2` matched? If yes, 1, else, 0:
  mutate(score = ifelse(
    str_detect(value, paste0(df2, collapse = "|")), 1, 0)) %>%
  # for each distinct row:
  group_by(rn) %>%
  # calculate the sum of `score`:
  summarise(across(c(name, value)), 
                   total_score = sum(score)) %>%
  # unnest the pivoted-longer columns back:
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, 
              values_from = value,
              values_fn = toString) %>%
  # create the `Flag` column:
  mutate(Flag = ifelse(total_score > 2, "Yes", "No"))
# A tibble: 4 × 7
# Groups:   rn [4]
     rn total_score Col_1          Col_2          Col_3    Col_4    Flag 
  <int>       <dbl> <chr>          <chr>          <chr>    <chr>    <chr>
1     1           4 Maths, Science Science L      Commerce CS, Engg Yes  
2     2           3 Engg           Science, Maths NA       NA       Yes  
3     3           0 Commerce       English,       NA       NA       No   
4     4           4 Engg           Science, Engg  Science  NA       Yes
```

If you don't want `rn` and `total_score` then add `%>% select(-c(rn, total_score))`

**EDIT**:

If the goal is, as transpires from OP's comments, to flag rows in which certain keywords, such as for example "Maths", "Science", and "Engg", **all** must occur, then this rather straightforward regex-based solution works:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(All_cols = apply(df0, 1, paste, collapse = " "),
         Flag = ifelse(str_detect(All_cols, "(?=.*Maths)(?=.*Science)(?=.*Engg)"), 
                       "Yes", 
                       "No")) %>%
  select(-All_cols)
    # A tibble: 4 × 5
      Col_1         Col_2         Col_3    Col_4   Flag 
      <chr>         <chr>         <chr>    <chr>   <chr>
    1 Maths/Science Science L     Commerce CS/Engg Yes  
    2 Engg          Science/Maths NA       NA      Yes  
    3 Commerce      English,      NA       NA      No   
    4 Engg          Science/Engg  Science  NA      No
```

Key to this solution are two things:

- a) we temporarily collapse all columns into a single string and
- b) we use positive lookahead to assert that the three key words all must be present in the strings as well as `ifelse` to create the `Flag` column.

**Data**:

```
df <- structure(list(Col_1 = c("Maths/Science", "Engg", "Commerce", 
                               "Engg"), Col_2 = c("Science L", "Science/Maths", "English,", 
                                                  "Science/Engg"), Col_3 = c("Commerce", "NA", "NA", "Science"), 
                     Col_4 = c("CS/Engg", "NA", "NA", "NA")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                            -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df2= c("Maths","Science","Engg")
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I don't get any error in code. But in Total_score and Flag column has only NA value.

Comment: Two questions: a) have you tried my code with **the data as posted in my answer**?, b) can you post **your data** using `dput(head(YOURDATA))` please?

Comment: Hi Chris, I have edited to include dput () and sample output in above request. Please help

Comment: Hi Chris, I have edited to include my output and dput() data. Kindly help

Comment: I've used your dput data and my code: it works perfectly. Can you please try again? (Also use the vector `df2= c("Maths","Science","Engg")` in that form.)

Comment: Thanks Chris, it works but the problem now is in last row we don't have Maths in any of column so Flag  has to be No. But here it shows Yes. Any Suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused: you have "Yes" for the 4th row in your expected outcome too!

Comment: No, only if  Maths, Science and Engg is present in a row, then Flag should be Yes else No. Since 4th row doesn't have Maths (In any of the column), the Flag should be No

Comment: So your expected output is incorrect?

Comment: Please see edited solution